# Cannot insert data in mysql database from windows form application in c++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2017

I'm using `VS-2017` and MySql 8.0 and I am trying to insert data from windows form application in `c++`; the project was run properly, but the query is not correct. I guess, when I insert data and click the save button I created, it says:

> "you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1"

[image]

But I can insert data from the code manually (you can see the comment in the code which work), but i can not insert from the form! I done everything according to this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_iZ9FR0JmE&index=10&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZz6uDid--I09EOImRmPHS0)

Now how can I do that? My code is here:

```
private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ constring = L"datasource= 127.0.0.1; port= 3306;username=root;password=12712";
    MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `university`.`student` (`id`,`name`,`password`)  values('"+this->id_txt->Text+"','"+this->name_txt->Text+"','"+this->password_txt->Text+"' ;", conDataBase);
   //MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `university`.`student` (`id`, `name`, `password`) VALUES ('7', 'ah', '77'); ", conDataBase);
```

Comment: Show the SQL error, and format the code. Show the table structure too `SHOW CREATE TABLE university.student`.

Comment: Sir, I have edited my post? Is it okey now? Do I also attach the screenshot of the sql error?

Comment: Sir, I also have attach the database table and sql error in the screenshot

Comment: @Sazzad Print and share formated query. Guess you have problem(s) with formating the query.

Comment: I also think, the problem is with the query, But I'm surprised same code worked in the tutorial I've share here, he done that in vs10, and I've check and recheck the code that I've done all the same as the tutorial. Now I don't understand why the same come should not work for me..